# Create JSON array with different number of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

What I am trying to do is to create a JSON with a different number of elements.

```
json = [
    {
        key: "test",
        values: [
            {
                "label" : "A" ,
                "value" : 29
            } ,
            {
                "label" : "B" , 
                "value" : 0
            } ,........
```

The number of the elements (and information itself) `values` will contain is not always the same.

1. How can I "push" elements (or an array?) into "values"?
2. How do I create an array where the elements have the same structure as "values"?

Comment: Just a note about JSON vs objects: JSON is a string and not an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different. The former is a data exchange format similar to YAML or XML while the latter is an actual object with properties and values.

Comment: @Amwiom yes, but it is represented using a string in JavaScript. I did mention it was a data exchange format if you continued to read the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `values` key points to an `array`. If that *never* changes ( meaning values will always be an array ) it doesn't matter what you try adding to it. Whether it's an array, object, or element you can use `.push()`

```
json[0].values.push(new_element_or_array_variable);
```

---

If you wanted to recreate an array with the same structure as value, well it would be just generally better to know how it's built, but lets say you go in blindly.

```
var json = [{
    key: "test",
    values: [{
        "label": "A",
            "value": 29
    }, {
        "label": "B",
            "value": 0
    }]
}];

var struct = json[0].values.map(function (a, b) {
    if (typeof a === 'object') {
        var obj = {};
        for (var key in a) {
            if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = -1;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
});

console.log(struct);
```

So then you have a copy of your values with empty objects.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7byxbhpg/)

---

**Update here:**

```
//...
for (var key in a) {
            if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = -1;
            }
        }
//...
```

Evey loop you do ( in the above code ) will access one by one each key in an object. So in the first loop ( = iteration ) key will contain "label", in the second iteration it will contain "value". To ensure you only take the structure of the first object and it doesn't take into account the rest simply do:

```
if (typeof a === 'object' && b == 0) {
        var obj = {};
        for (var key in a) {
            if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj[key] = -1;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Where `a` is the `object` and `b` is the index of that `object` within the `values array`.

---

Also notice that my map function only checks only if it's an object ( with typeof ). If you have integers, strings, or arrays you should check there types and deteremine what you want to do with them.

You could simply do:

```
    if (typeof a === 'object') {
        //... code here
    }else{
      return a;
    }
```

Comment: I guess user wants to push _inplace_ many elements, that is either use
json[0].values = json[0].values.concat(hisArray)
or json[0].values.push.apply(json[0].values, hisArray)
or simply json[0].values.push('value1',{someOtherValue:2})

Comment: Thanks Grimbode, I've added a second question which I forgot to add, do you also have the answer to that?

Comment: First, thanks! Second, Why is the if (typeof...) needed? How can I access "label" and "value"? Because "key" is both - label and value. But I want to set different values to them.

Comment: @user3549524 ah I made a little mistake. I'll update the question in a bit with the correct information. To make it clear, in the first iteration of the for loop: key actually refers *label* first, then in the second iteration of the loop it refers to *value*. Typeof is needed because imagine if your values array contains something other than objects. If you only send back objects then you wouldn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

> I've added a second question which I forgot to add, do you also have the answer to that?
>
> How do I create an array where the elements have the same structure as "values"?

you need an array and `object` like this

```
var values = [];
var obj = {};                     // line 1
obj.label= 'desired value';       // line 2
obj.value= 'desired value';
values.pust(obj);                 //line 3
```

you can put `line1-line3` in loop if you want to insert more than one in array.